# How can I config webpack to set file version?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, web-applications

I want to config webpack for give me the file version when I open the sources in inspect like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't have versions, but you can have `[contenthash]`on your filename that works almost the same as a version, but it is a hash generated based on the file content.

To do that:

```
output: {
   filename: 'bundle.[contenthash].js'
}
```

Comment: thank you but how this site did it?:( https://i.stack.imgur.com/cByQd.png

Comment: probably manually. There is no automatic way to do that. You could do the same, updating the filename manually.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my webpack.config.js output config like this:

`` output: {
      path: paths.build,
      chunkFilename: `[name].${process.env.RELEASE_ID}.[chunkhash:8].js`,
      filename: `[name].${process.env.RELEASE_ID}.[chunkhash:8].js`,
      publicPath: '/static/',
    }, ``

and it fixed :D